# Content review and scan

Tags: content-management

Is there any tool or any Sitecore module which is smart enough to extract all content from Sitecore CMS in pdf or any file so that content author or marketing team can review or audit before it is release to production?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the non-CMS users i.e. who do not have access to sitecore, we can extract content through Powershell extenstion Reports as shown:

**Sitecore Powershell Reports:**

[image: Powershell Reports]

**Extract Options:**

[image: Extract Options]

please note that we have many audit reports like

- Configuration Audit
- Content Audit
- Media Audit
- Solution Audit

we are frequently using Broken links audit which is very useful.

You can give a try :)

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore has a better way to audit content before going to live site.You don't have to convert your pages into PDF.  You can use sitecore workflow for reviewing content. Editor add content to your site and after they submit the page. One reviewer approve the content or reject it.  Reviewer can vizualize pages in the same way like a visitor.  If reviewer approve a page item goes to final step of workflow and can be published.

You can find more about workflows here: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/content_authoring/managing_items/workflows/workflows_and_the_workbox

How to review an item : https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/content_authoring/managing_items/workflows/review_an_item_in_the_workbox

How to move an item to other worflow state: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/content_authoring/managing_items/workflows/move_an_item_to_the_next_workflow_state

Comment: We have these in place, however just to have sanity check before we go live. We have all controls in place however to avoid any error in content.